# need to create click event programmatically for BulletedList

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, click, server-side

I have the following BulletedList with ListItem's in it. I need to give an onclick event to the listitems.

So my code:

```
BulletedList ul = new BulletedList();
ul.ID = "paginationDyn";
ul.DisplayMode = BulletedListDisplayMode.LinkButton;
ul.Click = //What needs to come up here?
```

What do I have to give in the `ul.Click`property? And also click method needs to be created.

Thanks

Comment: type `ul.Click += ` and it should provide it for you (press enter)

Comment: Do you want to add an event handler (as George seems to think) or do you want to fire the Click event?

Comment: I need to create event handlers for each `ListItem` within the `BulletedList`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ul.Click += new BulletedListEventHandler(ul_Click);
```

then else where in your code

```
void ul_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

If you are using Visual Studio, you can get auto completeion for this by typing the `+=`
and then pressing tab.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is:

```
    ...
    BulletedList ul = new BulletedList();
    ul.ID = "paginationDyn";
    ul.DisplayMode = BulletedListDisplayMode.LinkButton;
    ul.Click += new BulletedListEventHandler(ul_Click);
}

void ul_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to raise an event [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z.aspx) explains how to implement an event of your own.

If you just want to raise the built-in event of the BulletedList you need to create a sub class which calls OnClick.

```
public class MyBulletedList : BulletedList{
    protected void function doStuff(){
        OnClick();
    }
}
```

This will fire the click event of the BulletedList.